# Getting NameError on GetParameterAsText

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, parameters, nameerror

I am trying to write a simple script that get input from a variable in ModelBuilder and use it in a Python script to "zoom" on a selected features in layout.

Here is the script and the error:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
mapx = aprx.listMaps()[0]
lyr = mapx.listLayers()[4]
quartier = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

lyr.definitionQuery = '"NOM" = ' + "'"+GetParameterAsText(0)+"'"

lyt = aprx.listLayouts()[0]
mf = lyt.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT')[0]

mf.camera.setExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(lyr, False, True))
```

---

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users...\Projet\zoom.py", line 10, in 
> lyr.definitionQuery = '"NOM" = ' + "'"+GetParameterAsText(0)+"'" NameError: name 'GetParameterAsText' is not defined

The model variable and Python variables have the exact same name.
The model variable data type is set as a string.
The script variable datatype is set to all values.

My version of ArcGIS Pro is in French.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you have:

```
lyr.definitionQuery = '"NOM" = ' + "'"+GetParameterAsText(0)+"'"
```

it should be:

```
lyr.definitionQuery = '"NOM" = ' + "'"+arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)+"'"
```

However, since you have previously set `quartier = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)` you could also use Python string formatting to do the same thing:

```
lyr.definitionQuery = "NOM = '{0}'".format(quartier)
```